# EnergyPlus FMU in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, fmi, energyplus

I am trying to integrate a building modeled in EnergyPlus inside Simulink.

Wanting to start simple I began from the example files provided by the developers of the .fmu software [LINK](http://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/fmu/EnergyPlus/export/index.html) and successfully generated a .fmu file of a building.

I then designed a simple simulink software to test the integration but I experience immediate crashes every time I try to run the program, I don't receive any error message to use as clue for debugging.

Has anyone already tried this kind of integration?

I am working on a Windows10 machine, with Matlab r2016b, EnergyPlus 8.6 and EnergyPlusToFmu 2.0.2.

Comment: Which software or "toolbox" are you using to import the FMU into Simulink?

Comment: the official matlab PSP fmi toolbox

Comment: Can you import other FMUs, such as the ones available from www.fmi-standard.org? If that works, can you share the test-FMU you are trying to import into Simulink?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to run the FMU Compliance Checker (from https://www.fmi-standard.org/downloads) on the FMU.
If no errors are found, you should contact the Mathworks support, otherwise the developers of EnergyPlus2FMU.